# ¿Cómo cambiar o quitar el titulo de la barra de notificaciones de Windows (Notifyicon)?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, notifyicon

Uso el componente `NotifyIcon` en una `app` de `Windows`, pero al momento de mostrar la notificación en la barra de notificaciones, el `título` de esas notificaciones aparece por defecto con el nombre del `namespace` de la app, y quiero que ese titulo sea diferente, que en lugar de tomarlo por defecto del `namespace` yo pueda establecerlo.

Este es un ejemplo de lo que aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> En este caso toma el `namespace` y lo coloca de título **ControlPC**

Lo que busco es cambiar ese título o desaparecerlo, pero no encuentro la propiedad o función para hacerlo.

Comment: Creo que te refieres a la propiedad "BalloonTipTitle", esa es la que Obtiene o establece el título del globo de sugerencias mostrado en el NotifyIcon.

Comment: No, esa propiedad es donde dice "Aviso"

Comment: Hola, te sirve la idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de buscar, encontré el lugar exacto de donde toma por defecto el nombre para el título de las notificaciones.

Está en **`Propierties > AssemblyInfo.cs`**.

Exactamente en la propiedad:

> [assembly: AssemblyTitle("Nuevo título")]

Comment: Q bien, voy a probar

Answer (score 4):

Hace un tiempo me sucedió exactamente lo mismo, mis notificaciones funcionaban perfectamente en **Windows 10**, pero con una actualización
que se le hizo al S.O mis notificaciones empezaron a presentar el problema que mencionas, además, de que en **Windows 7** las notificaciones
nunca se mostraron y el estilo de las mismas era diferente al de **Windows 10**.

Investigué mucho en Internet, y no encontré ninguna solución que me convenciera ni que funcionara, es decir, seguía en las mismas.
Entre algunas de las posibles soluciones que encontré estaba crear una llave en el registro de Windows, e incluso muchos decían
que era hasta un problema del **Windows 10**(no lo afirmo yo).

Al ver que después de buscar tanto nada servía me decidí a crear yo mismo mis propias notificaciones, y esta es la solución que te
propongo:

Lo primero que hice fue tirarle una foto con **PrintScreen** a una notificación real, esta la recorté y la modifiqué a mi gusto en el Paint.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente creé un formulario en mi proyecto y le configuré las siguientes propiedades:

**Name:** FrmNotificacion

**FormBorderStyle:** None

**MaximizeBox:** False

**MinimizeBox:** False

**ShownInTaskBar:** False

**Size:** 363; 122

**StartPosition:** WindowsDefaultLocation

**Text:** ""

**WindowState:** Normal

A este formulario le añadí un **PictureBox** y le puse la imagen que diseñé de la notificación.
Abajo del texto **Información** añadí un **Label** que sería el que me va a mostrar el texto de la notificación.

Al **Label** le configuré las siguientes propiedades:

**Name:** lblMensaje

**AutoSize:** False

**BackColor:** 56; 58; 60

**Font:** Segoe UI; 9pt

**ForeColor:** Info

**Location:** 89; 78

**Size:** 262; 35

**TextAlign:** TopLeft

Y por último añadí un **Timer**, para que  mi notificación se cerrara pasado un tiempo(**3 segundos**).

Al **Timer** le configuré las siguientes propiedades:

**Enabled:** True

**Interval:** 1000

Hasta aquí mi diseño de la notificación, ahora vendría el código:

```
public partial class FrmNotificacion : Form
{
    static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
    static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
    static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
    static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
    const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;
    int tiempo = 0;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
  
    public FrmNotificacion(string txtNotificacion)
    {           
        InitializeComponent();
        lblMensaje.Text = txtNotificacion;
        SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
    }

    private void FrmNotificacion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
        this.Left = Screen.GetBounds(this).Width - this.Width - 15;
        this.Top = Screen.GetBounds(this).Height - this.Height - 45;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (e.X >= 328 && e.X <= 340 && e.Y >= 20 && e.Y <= 30)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (++tiempo >= 3)
        {
            tiempo = 0;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Lo primero que debo resolver al mostrar la notificación es asegurarme de que esta se muestre por encima de cualquier formulario
y que no se esconda al dar clic en otro formulario, es decir que se mantenga activa hasta que yo la cierre manualmente o se agote el tiempo en que va a estar mostrado el formulario de la notificación, para lograr esto utilizo la **función** **SetWindowPos del API de Windows**, para ello debo importarla tal como muestro en el código (esto es lo único raro que hay en el código).

Modifico el constructor del **Formulario** para que reciba un parámetro de tipo **string** que sería el texto a mostrar quedando de esta forma:

```
public FrmNotificacion(string txtNotificacion)
{           
    InitializeComponent();
    lblMensaje.Text = txtNotificacion;
    SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
}
```

Aquí muestro el mensaje en el **Label** y emito un sonido propio del sistema operativo.

En el **Load** del **Formulario** pongo:

```
    private void FrmNotificacion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
        this.Left = Screen.GetBounds(this).Width - this.Width - 15;
        this.Top = Screen.GetBounds(this).Height - this.Height - 45;
    }
```

LLamo la **función** **SetWindowPos** y ubico el formulario de notificaciones en la esquina inferior derecha de la pantalla. Como el formulario de notificaciones no tiene bordes no puedo cerrarlo manualmente ya que los botones de cerrar, maximizar y minimizar no son visibles, por tanto, como yo puse una imagen que ya tiene la **X** para cerrar la aplicación, debo simular que cuando se de clic en ese cuadrante de la imagen se cierre
el **Formulario**, para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (e.X >= 328 && e.X <= 340 && e.Y >= 20 && e.Y <= 30)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Y por último programo en el **evento** **OnTick** del **Timer**, para que pasado un tiempo, si no he cerrado manualmente la **notificación** esta se cierre automáticamente
pasado **3 segundos**:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (++tiempo >= 3)
        {
            tiempo = 0;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Debes incorporar en los **usings**:

```
using System.Media; //Para ejecutar el sonido al mostrar la notificación
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //Para importar la función SetWindowPos de la API de Windows
```

Para llamar la notificación harías:

```
new FrmNotificacion("Mensaje de notificacion").Show();
```

Imagen de la notificación diseñada por mi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La ventaja que tiene hacer tu propia notificación es que la puedes diseñar como quieras, es fácil de hacer, va a funcionar de la misma forma independientemente del **Sistema Operativo**, y apenas lleva código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte colega, tal vez me sirva para otra cosa.